# intercept disappear adding interaction term with dummy variable and factor variable in panel regression

Tags: r, panel, interaction, intercept

I am running a panel regression using time fixed effect when adding the interaction term between one dummy variable (sex: 0-male, 1-female) and categorical variable (industry sector by GICS: i.e utilities, real estate etc). The dependent variable is wage.

I am doing `r1<-plm(wage ~ gender * industry + control variables, data=d,model = "within",effect = "time")`

Result shows:

`GICSConsumer Discretionary` `0.116` `0.005*`

`Sex:GICSConsumer Discretionary` `-0.0550509` `0.002*`

I have omit results for the rest 10 industries but I didn't find the intercept and seemingly one industry just disappeared (that's the first industry in one GICS variable). I tried `r1<-plm(wage ~ gender * industry -1 + control variables, data=d,model = "within",effect = "time")` but not working. I know I can change to lm but just wonder how to do so in plm.

Thank you

Comment: Inform yourself about contrasts (specifically treatment contrasts).

Comment: Thxs Roland, would you mind clarifying what you mean by  treatment contrasts? thxs

Comment: See `help("contr.treatment")` and a simple google search should clarify what treatment contrasts are and why there can't be a separate parameter for the reference level.